# Issue with Crystal Reports, SQL Server jobs

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, crystal-reports

I have two Server `DEVSSIS` and `DEVAPPS1`.

`DEVSSIS` is where SQL Server jobs reside, it runs the operating system (`CmdExcc`) i.e exe file which is located on `DEVAPPS1` server.

`DEVAPPS1` server is where exe of console application written in C# resides. Crystal Reports is installed on this server. That exe file generates a report.

Issue: when I run the application from `devapps1` server, it works perfectly fine and generates the pdf report.

Now when I try to run SQL Server jobs from DEVSSIS server I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I try many things but did not find a solution for the issue. One thing I did not do is install Crystal Report on `DEVSSIS` server because it runs only a SQL Server job. Do I have to install it on `DEVSSIS` server? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CR needs to be installed on the same computer were the application is running. In your case, DEVSSIS is running the .exe so it requires CR to be installed.

Comment: Actually the console app .exe file is on DEVAPPS1. Now the CmdExec path  From the DEVSSIS server is like this
\\DEVAPPS1\Applications\ApplicationDevelopments\Assessments\Assessments.exe

Comment: it only tells run the application from that path but it still runs on the DEVSSIS computer. So CR needs to be installed there as well